# Stripe Authentication

Tags: authentication, stripe-payments

I am not able to authenticate in stripe.com  - using Basic Authentication

```
public class Str extends HttpServlet {


    protected void doGet(HttpServletRequest request, HttpServletResponse response) throws ServletException, IOException {
        PrintWriter pw=response.getWriter();
        pw.println("Hello World");
        HttpClient client= new HttpClient();
        String req="https://api.stripe.com/";
        client.getParams().setAuthenticationPreemptive(true);
        client.getState().setCredentials(new AuthScope(req, 443, null),  new UsernamePasswordCredentials("<api-key>"));
        client.getHostConfiguration().setHost(req, 443, "https");

        PostMethod post= new PostMethod("https://api.stripe.com/v1/charges/");
        //post.addParameter("id", "<id>");
        int status=client.executeMethod(post);
        pw.println(status);



    }


}
```

i am presenting my code...where i hv used HTTP Basic Auth to provide the users credentials to stripe.com

Comment: And what happens when you try?

Comment: it says that no default credentials found..and Authentication failed

Comment: Why not use the Stripe Java bindings? https://stripe.com/docs/libraries

Answer (score 0):

Try: `new UsernamePasswordCredentials("<api-key>", "")`

Answer (score 0):

Hope this will help you.

Here API_KEY means secrete key

```
HttpResponse httpResponse;
String request ='card[number]='+card_name+'&card[exp_year]='+card_exp_year+'&card[exp_month]='+card_exp_month+'&card[cvc]='+card_cvv+'&amount='+amount+ '&currency='+currency;
Http httpObject = new Http();
HttpRequest httpRequest = new HttpRequest();
httpRequest.setEndpoint(sHttpEndPoint);
httpRequest.setMethod('POST');
Blob headerValue = Blob.valueOf(API_KEY + ':');
String authorizationHeader = 'BASIC ' +
EncodingUtil.base64Encode(headerValue);
httpRequest.setHeader('Authorization', authorizationHeader);
httpRequest.setBody(request);  
httpResponse = httpObject.send(httpRequest);
```